# Python Binary addition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to add 2 binary numbers, however my program doesn't work properly. Please look through my code and advise me in any errors. Thanks.
This is the code:

```
import time
n=0
while n!=1:
    error1=True
    while error1:
        try:
            bin2dec = raw_input("Please enter a binary number: ")
            bin2dec2 = raw_input("Please enter a binary number: ")
            error1=False
        except NameError:
            print"Enter a Binary number. Please try again.\n"
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except SyntaxError:
            print"Enter a Binary number. Please try again.\n"
            time.sleep(0.5)


    decnum=0

    for i in bin2dec: 
        decnum = decnum * 2 + int(i)

    decnum2=0

    for i in bin2dec2: 
        decnum2 = decnum2 * 2 + int(i)
        dectotal=decnum+decnum2
        b = ''            
        b = str(dectotal % 2) + b
        dectotal >>= 1
        print b,
    print"<<This is your answer"
```

Comment: so you just want us to write the rest of the code for you? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. -1

Comment: Just do `bin(int(n1, 2) + int(n2, 2))[2:]`

Comment: can't get the question

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Rayner. As you've discovered, the site is intended for questions about concrete programming tasks, so please clarify yours. Your result is already "stored" in the variable `b`, what exactly do you want to know how to do with it?

Comment: Sorry "b" is not the variable I want to store its is decnum. I want the user to enter 2 binary numbers, as I'm a noob to python I have to go the long way from   bininput>decconvert>storeinvariable then, get the second input bin>decconvert>storeinvariable and finally add the 2 dec numbers and convert to binary and print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should fit your requirements quite nicely, while being much, much shorter:

```
print (lambda x,y: bin(int(x,2)+int(y,2))[2:])(raw_input(),raw_input())
```

The following would be even better:

```
a="Enter Number";ri=raw_input;print "Sum: "+(lambda x,y: bin(int(x,2)+int(y,2))[2:])(ri(a+' 1: '),ri(a+' 2: '))
```

Since you can't use bin or dec, try the following. It doesn't use bin, and doesn't use dec. It also doesn't use variable assignment, def statements, multiple statements, or int. In fact, it doesn't even use built-in addition, multiplication or division for the numbers themselves:

```
print "Sum: "+(lambda q: "".join(reversed([ (lambda n: n[0+(None!=q.__setitem__(0,n[1]))])
((lambda x,y,z: (lambda v: (str(v%2),str(v/2)))
((ord(x)-48)+(ord(y)-48)+(ord(z)-48)))(x,y,q[0])) 
for x,y in reversed(zip(raw_input("Enter Number 1: ").zfill(16),
raw_input("Enter Number 2: ").zfill(16)))])))(['0'])
```

Note that while this works, and I would encourage you to examine it, if you submit it as an exam answer, I am not responsible for any loss of points or injury to you by angry examiners.

Comment: My Exam board specification says I can't use the bin function so that the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RaynerDaCruz: There's probably a way to get around that: `__builtins__.__dict__['nib'[::-1]]()`

Comment: @Blender: technically correct is best correct

Comment: My third version should satisfy the requirements then.